# Spring. access to webapp\resources directory

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-mvc, io

I have written the following spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getVideoIcon")
    @ResponseBody
    public FileSystemResource getVideoIcon() throws IOException {
        return new FileSystemResource(new File("/resources/images/video_icon.png"));
    }
```

The file is located at `src\main\webapp\resources\images`

When I invoke the controller I get following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - resources\images\video_icon.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Please help to correct my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to get the original project's path, you should use `getServletContext().getRealPath`

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getVideoIcon")
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getVideoIcon(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/images")+"/video_icon.png";
    return new FileSystemResource(new File(path));
}
```

If you need to check what the `path` variable is holding, use `System.out.println(path);` before the return statement. If you're still experiencing error message after trying the above code, feel free to ask..

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write a controller to support static resources in Spring application.

Add this to your Spring xml configuration:

```xml
<mvc:resources mapping="/image/**" location="/resources/images/" />
```

In JSP page, you can use it like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<img src="<c:url value="/image/video_icon.png" />" />
```

Comment: and how to access to resource on the page after writing this?

Comment: you can access a resource as you define in mapping, eg. in jsp file: <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/video_icon.png" />" /> and add taglib prefix <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Comment: what if i want to write a file in that directory in javacode?